# How to find the time until a certain date in Python, for a specific TimeZone?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, datediff

I want to create a script that outputs the amount of time remaining (as "X hours, Y minutes, Z seconds remaining") until 27th August 9 AM (in IST).

This is what I tried:

```
import datetime

delta = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 27) - datetime.datetime.now()
total_seconds = delta.total_seconds()
s = int(total_seconds)

print s
```

This prints `4439`, which is the wrong answer. I'm guessing it's a timezone issue. My timezone is `Asia/Kolkata` and the correct answer should be `36720`.

How can this be done?

Comment: The code seems to be working for me. I am in U.S. Eastern Standard Time. Are you logged into a VM or some other place? Where are you testing this? I tried the same code here as well. http://ideone.com/L32Wym

Comment: @abhi: The output should be showing 36720 (~10 hours) as written in the question, but the current output is wrong.

Comment: I'm testing this on my local linux setup.

Comment: Is your linux box have the proper locals and timezone?

Comment: Let work with fixed values : delta = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 27) - datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 26, 13, 30) I get 37800 when I set Asia/Kolkata as a timezone in my linux box...

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead, I suspect the int() messes with the total_seconds object.

```
import datetime

delta = datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 27) - datetime.datetime.now()
total_seconds = (delta).total_seconds()


print total_seconds
```